# How to make this HTML/Javascript random number generator output multiple results?

Tags: javascript, html

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. I have a simple onload random number generator I am having issues with.

Basically I am trying to insert the generated number between some text. I am having no luck, but seems like I have tried everything. It always puts a line between the phrase.

My second issue is I can't figure out how to have more than one random number output. I am new to JavaScript so any explanation would be more than appreciated!

```js
function getNumber() {
  var minNumber = 10; // The minimum number you want
  var maxNumber = 10; // The maximum number you want
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber);
  document.getElementById("myNumber").innerHTML = randomnumber;
  // Sets content of <div> to number
  return false;
}
window.onload = getNumber;
```

```html
<div id="myNumber"> </div>
<p id="yourNumber"> </p>
```

```
I am (random number) years old.
My brother is (random number) years old. 
My dog had (random number) puppies last year.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the *output*-element, since it is supposed to be used for results... And I use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the output-elements.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  function getNumber() {
    output => output.value = getNumber();
    var minNumber = 10; // The minimum number you want
    var maxNumber = 20; // The maximum number you want
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber);
  }

  // Using querySelectorAll to get all output-elements, and then update the value of the output-element with a random number.
  document.querySelectorAll('output').forEach(
    output => output.value = getNumber()
  );
});
```

```html
<div>I am <output name="me"></output> years old.</div>
<div>My brother is <output name="brother"></output> years old. </div>
<div>My dog had <output name="dog"></output> puppies last year. </div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you for the assistance, I see what the issue was.

Answer (score 1):

I would break down the tasks into a function that generates the random number and another one that updates the DOM.

That way, you can re-use the number generator

Kind of like this (see demo)

```js
// gets a random number
function getNumber() {
  var minNumber = 10; // The minimum number you want
  var maxNumber = 10; // The maximum number you want
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber);
  return randomNumber;
}

// updates one DOM element given its id
function updateDom(id) {
  var aRandomNumber = getNumber();
  // Sets content of <div> to number
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = aRandomNumber;
}

// updates all DOM elements listed
function updateAll() {
  updateDom('myNumber');
  updateDom('yourNumber');
  updateDom('theirNumber');
}

// when window ready, call function
window.onload = updateAll();
```

```html
<div>I am <span id='myNumber'></span> years old.</div>
<div>My brother is <span id='yourNumber'></span> years old. </div>
<div>My dog had <span id='theirNumber'></span> puppies last year. </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` is by default displayed with CSS `display: block`, which puts it on its own line. You could either set your own custom CSS, but I recommend you use `<span>` instead, which by default uses `display: inline`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this or do you need a number between 10 and 10? You can't have any number between 10 and 10 beside 10.

```js
function getNumber() {
  var minNumber = 10; // The minimum number you want
  var maxNumber = 10; // The maximum number you want
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  document.getElementById("myNumber").innerHTML = randomnumber;
  // Sets content of <div> to number
  return false;
}
window.onload = getNumber;
```

```html
<div id="myNumber"> </div>
<p id="yourNumber"> </p>
```